# Why does the performance on the training set go down as the number of samples increases?

Tags: neural-networks, scikit-learn, training-error, learning

To my knowledge there are two types of learning curves, those that show the progression of the performance as the amount of epochs progresses, and those that show the performance progression as the amount of training data increases. I am referring to the second type. Here is the plot, as made with `sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve`:
[image]

I observed that my training metric goes down as the number of training samples increases. I wanted to double check whether my reasoning is correct. I assume this happens because when there is only a small amount of training data, the model (simple neural network in this case) is able to accurately learn large parts of the training set (maybe even overfit). So the model has enough complexity to hold the information that describes the training data. As we add more data, it becomes a harder task for the model to 'learn by heart' the training data, and a more complex model would be necessary to maintain the same training set performance. Is this reasoning correct? Or are there other things at play?

Comment: Note that "maintaining training set performance" is not a goal. What matters is generalization - performance on unseen data, and the validation/test set is supposed to represent that

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware that maintaining a good training set performance is not the end goal. I was just curious why it goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning sounds correct.

You can check it by trying larger model sizes. (Although such comparisons have a small chance of being distorted due to having more or less luck during hyperparameter search for the larger model than for the small model.)

Also note that you have to either define (formulate mathematically) what you mean by "learn by heart" etc. and then you can check precisely to what extent that is happening (your measurement of the performance on the training vs. validation set probably does exactly that), or if you don't want to formulate it mathematically, then exact sciences probably can't answer your question.